# Come si dice "meme" in italiano?

Tags: translation, single-words

Buongiorno,

Come si traduce il termine "meme" in italiano (quelle sigle con un'immagine dietro che si vedono girare su Facebook e Internet). Inoltre vorrrei sapere dove posso trovare, se non vi dispiace, dei testi "mene" in italiano dai quali trarre ispirazione, modificare, e riusare. Scusate se questo è un po' off-topic, sono un po' imbranato.

Molte grazie per la vostra pazienza.

Comment: Quanto a testi e spiritosaggini, sì, qui sono fuori tema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Meme* si dice in italiano “[meme](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/meme_(Neologismi)/)”, ovviamente pronunciato all'italiano e con come plurale “memi” (sul modello di “gene” e “geni”).

Nota che il concetto di meme è ben più ampio delle spiritosaggini su Internet e descrive qualsiasi elemento culturale, idea, anche una singola nuova parola che si diffonde e si modifica all'interno della società in un modo confrontabile con quello appunto dei geni. Cioè il meme starebbe alla cultura come il gene alla biologia.

Comment: Può aiutare sapere che *meme* in inglese è un'abbreviazione di *mimeme* dal greco μίμημα e per somiglianza con *gene* (dall'etimologia scorrelata). Perciò a rigor di logica in italiano avremmo dovuto tradurlo con *mema* o *mimema* ma abbiamo (ragionevolmente) preferito conservare la somiglianza con *gene*.

Comment: Sinceramente non ho mai sentito usare "memi", il plurale di un termine straniero resta immutato, quindi penso sia comunque "meme"

Comment: Ma questo non è un termine straniero, @pinckerman, è un termine italiano che per caso ha la stessa forma del termine straniero, esattamente come “gene”. Dici per caso “i gene”? Comunque, nella pagina della Treccani che cito c'è anche un esempio di “memi” al plurale.

Comment: Ho capito il ragionamento, ma _meme_ riferito esclusivamente alle immagini virali di Internet l'ho sempre interpretato quasi come un nome proprio. Poi d'accordo, "meme" in senso lato deriva dal greco ed esiste anche nella nostra lingua.